# Why does my code run successfully as a console app, but throws an exception as a class library? C# Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices

Tags: c#, class, console-application, exchangewebservices, class-library

I am new to C# and I am working on a project that utilized the Microsoft.WebServices.Data DLL (from NuGet) to connect to and Exchange account and move emails that fall within the specified date range in one folder to another folder (on the same account). Long story short, my project runs successfully with no issues as a console app (.exe), but fails when I try to use it as a DLL (in conjunction with the EWS DLL).

Here is the exception that I receive: (Updated 20190822 14:28 CST)

```
Message: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase' threw an exception.

Inner Exception: System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetFullPathWithAssert(String fileName)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsUtilities.<.cctor>b__9()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LazyMember`1.get_Member()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsUtilities.get_BuildVersion()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase..cctor()

StackTrace :   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase..ctor(TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService..ctor(ExchangeVersion requestedServerVersion)
   at Outlook_iHM.MoveEmails.FindAndMoveEmails(String username, String password, String origFolderName, String moveToFolderName, String startDate, String endDate)
```

I have read through the documentation on MSDN, declaring the TimeZoneInfo, ensuring that all reference files are located within the same folder, placing variables outside of the method(s), using different Target Frameworks, using different types of Class Libraries (.NET Framework, .NET Standard). I have been Googleing it, searching through StackOverflow, and trying to find YouTube video tutorials that may assist. I have also tested it on two different machines with the same results on each.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace OutlookLibrary
{
    public class MoveEmails
    {
        internal static FolderId findFolderIdByName(ExchangeService service, string folderName)
        {
            FindFoldersResults searchResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(int.MaxValue) { Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep });
            foreach (Folder folder in searchResults.Folders)
            {
                if (folder.DisplayName == folderName)
                {
                    return folder.Id;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        public static string findAndMoveEmails(string username, string password, string origFolderName, string moveToFolderName, string startDate, string endDate)
        {
            string passFail;

            try
            {
                var output = new List<ItemId>();

                // Convert date strings to DateTime
                DateTime sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
                DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);

                // Exchange Service
                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);
                service.AutodiscoverUrl(username);

                // Get FolderIds
                FolderId origFolderId = findFolderIdByName(service, origFolderName);
                FolderId moveToFolderId = findFolderIdByName(service, moveToFolderName);

                // Search criteria
                List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new List<SearchFilter>();
                searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeSent, sDate));
                searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsLessThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeSent, eDate));
                SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, searchFilterCollection.ToArray());

                // Create view
                ItemView view = new ItemView(100000);
                view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
                view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeSent, SortDirection.Descending);

                // Search for the emails and filter out anything that is not an email message
                FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(origFolderId, searchFilter, view);
                foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults.Items)
                {
                    if (item is EmailMessage)
                    {
                        output.Add(item.Id);
                    }
                }

                // Move each email
                foreach (ItemId email in output)
                {
                    PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
                    EmailMessage origMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, email, propSet);
                    Item item = origMessage.Move(moveToFolderId);
                }
                passFail = "TRUE";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string path = @"C:\Logs\Error.txt";
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                {
                    sw.Write(string.Format("Message: {0}{1}StackTrace :{2}{1}Date :{3}{1}-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{1}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace, DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                }
                passFail = "FALSE";
            }

            //Return result
            return passFail;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the message notes, the exception is happening while running the static constructor of a type; that's bad. Does the debugger or the message tell you what the thrown exception was?

Comment: I am not sure. This is actually my first dll build, and after building it, I am accessing it through an automation software that supports dll's, which only presents an message box that explains that there is an error in the dll. If you have any ideas or suggestions on how I can find this information for you, I am more than willing to do so. I am still very fresh, so I apologize in advance.

Comment: The improved error message that you posted is telling us what is wrong. Somehow you are passing a wrong path, so focus on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
StackTrace :   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase..ctor(TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService..ctor(ExchangeVersion requestedServerVersion)
   at Outlook_iHM.MoveEmails.FindAndMoveEmails(String username, String password, String origFolderName, String moveToFolderName, String startDate, String endDate)
```

This is the important part. This tells you where in code it failed. The stackTrace When reading a stackTrace you always start at the bottom. The bottom should point to some point in your own code. In this case it says that path the code took was a function called FindAndMoveEmails which i see in your code you provided.

In that function (reading the next line up of the stack trace) it called what looks like a class constructor called Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService..ctor. Guessing constructor because of the cut off "ctor" at the end of the location specified. In your code, it is this line:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
```

The last line up in the stackTrace shows that the ExchangeService class is calling its base constructor and that is where it is failing. So it doesn't like something about your "ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1" parameter you are providing when run as a DLL.

If your DLL is running on your same machine as you are running the console app on then this would be kind of odd. But if your DLL is running on a different machine like a server then a few issues can come up. Its not JUST a difference of console vs DLL.

I will modify answer here if you provide clarification on your running environment.

Comment: Thank you CarCar. Very helpful on the Stack Trace clarification too. I built the code and compiled it on my work laptop. From there, I copied the code from the bin folder into my dev VM that resides on a server. I was able to successfully run the compiled console app on both my laptop and the VM. The software application that is utilizing the compiled DLL is on the VM. On another note, I did try leaving the ExchangeVersion blank (to default) and several different versions, but with the same result.

Comment: This is a good start on an analysis; one minor point to note is that an *instance* constructor is `.ctor`, but the *static* constructor -- the "class constructor" -- is `.cctor`.  The text of the error suggests that it is a `.cctor` that is failing, and it is    at `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase..cctor()`

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, here is how I resolved the issue:

Download and install Microsoft Exchange Web Service Managed API on the machine.

(In this case, it is the Virtual Machine that is utilizing my class library and the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll. | Note: The prod VM is a basic setup of windows, so no Visual Studio, etc., unlike my dev machine.)

EWS Managed API 2.2 found here: [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951)